# Count of Persons with Quota

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table `FarmerGroups` with data as follows

```
Farmer ID | Farmer Name | PROD_EST | Season
----------+-------------+----------+--------
001       | FRANK MENA  | 560      |  3
003       | KEVIN B ROSE| 127      |  2
```

I need to take count of farmers for season 3 that have prod_est in the following ranges:

```
0-100 Tons
100 - 250 Tons
250 - 500 Tons
500 - 1000 Tons
1000 - 5000 Tons
5000 - 10000 Tons
10000 Plus Tons
```

Example output:

```
COUNT | RANGE
------+-------
  100 | 0-100
   50 | 100-250
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Also sql-server-2012 seems too old. Please try to upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: a count of farmer within those ranges;

Comment: COUNT(number) | 0-100

Answer (score 1):

```
; WITH cteGroup as (
    SELECT ProdEst 
        , CASE WHEN ProdEst  <= 100 AND ProdEst  >= 0 
               THEN 'G1'
            WHEN ProdEst  <= 250  AND ProdEst  > 100 
               THEN 'G2'
            WHEN ProdEst  <= 500  AND ProdEst  > 250 
               THEN 'G3'
            -- ...
            WHEN ProdEst  <= 10000  AND ProdEst  > 5000 
               THEN 'G6'
            ELSE 'G7' END as Grp
    FROM FarmerGroups 
    WHERE Season = 3
)SELECT Count(*) as [COUNT]
    , CASE WHEN Grp = 'G1' THEN '0-100 Tons'
        WHEN Grp = 'G2' THEN '100-250 Tons'
        WHEN Grp = 'G3' THEN '250-500 Tons'
        -- ...
        WHEN Grp = 'G7' THEN '10000 Plus Tons'
    END as [RANGE]
FROM cteGroup
GROUP BY Grp
```

Comment: I had to use CASE WHEN PROD_EST  >= 1 AND PROD_EST  <= 100 THEN 'G1'

Comment: I tested it on SQL 2014 with just the <= XXX and it worked, sorry I didn't know it needed the extra on your version. Did it otherwise work for you? If so, please do mark it as accepted, and if not please explain what error you get.